# Vue project can't find image when using <a href> but can find it when using <img>

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have this Vue project. All I've done is run `vue create foo` and removed all the pre-created code that comes in the src folder when you run that command. I then added an image to the src folder and created my own `App.vue`, this is all I've written in it.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./foo.png">
    <a href="./foo.png" download>foo</a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>
```

When I then try it out with `npm run serve` the website displays the image perfectly fine, but the download link does not work. It says the server doesn't have the requested file or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue loader [automatically transforms img src attributes in templates into webpack module requests](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html), but by default it doesn't do the same for links.

If you need to link directly to a file, you can put it in the `public/` directory to bypass webpack (using a path relative to that directory -- i.e. for a file in `public/foo/bar.jpg` you'd use `<a href="/foo/bar.jpg">`)

Alternatively, you can leave the file where it is, and [tell webpack to transform `<a href>` urls](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader) into module requests, just as it does image src urls, by changing the [transformAssetUrls](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#transformasseturls) options:

```
/* Add to vue.config.js */
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
            .rule("vue")
            .use("vue-loader")
            .loader("vue-loader")
            .tap(options => {
                // modify the options...
                options = Object.assign(options, {
                    transformAssetUrls: {
                        a: "href"
                    }
                });
                return options;
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: How do i refer to it when it is in public?

Comment: Good point, I should have included that in the answer, I've added it now.